# Understanding the Home renovation tax credit in ontario

Tags: canada, ontario, tax-credit, home-renovation

I am trying to figure out the [home renovation tax credit](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/5006-s12/5006-s12-14e.pdf)

Does it only apply to the home I live in? If I currently live in a rental property  but am allowed to do renovations, can I apply for the credit?

What about my investment property? If I do renovations on the investment property, do I qualify for the credit?